# how to save the cropped image in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have done like getting an image from gallery. Display it into another View. I can crop that image, but I am unable to save it. Please anybody help me how to do this.

```
 - (IBAction)cropClicked:(id)sender
   {
   [self.cropImgView crop];

   }
   - (void)JBCroppableImageView:(JBCroppableImageView *)controller didFinishCroppingImage:(UIImage *)croppedImage{
   imag = croppedImage;
   secondViewController *second=[[secondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
   second.cutimage.image=croppedImage;

   //   [[self navigationController] pushViewController:second animated:YES];

   //  [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];

   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

   }
```

I followed this link  http://code4app.net/ios/Croppable-View/50ecd42a6803fadd48000000

Comment: Where do you want to save the image ?

Comment: thankyou for replying me .i need to display into on previous view image

Comment: put this [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; in the first line, and you need to push the second view.

Comment: what i did nt get u ..can  u explain it clearly

Comment: Wait, I guess you want to show the image to another viewcontroller or, the same viewcontroller you are capturing image ?

Comment: captured image or cropped image

Comment: i am getting an image from gallery and its displaying in sameviewController and click next button its go to second view with previous image then click crop btn image can be crop ..but which is not displaying into the first view when i click back button

Answer (score 0):

```
    To Save Crop image:
    First of all add property cutimage in FirstViewController.h file

        @interface FirstViewController
        @property (nonatomic , strong) UIImageView *cutimage;
        @end

        also initialize it in viewdidload of FirstViewcontoller 
        cutimage = [[UIImageView alloc] init]




    FirstViewController *objFirstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    objFirstViewController.objFirstVC = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objFirstViewController animated:NO] ;


     1. Create a property in .h file within 

        @interface SecondViewController  

        @property (nonatomic, strong) FirstViewController *objFirstViewController

        @end

     2. now within JBCroppableImageView method

        objFirstViewController.cutimage.image=croppedImage

    now within FirstViewcontroller "cutimage" object could be accessed to show CroppedImage.
```

Comment: no need to create secondviewcontroller object , just need to add above line in the .h file in which JBCroppableImageView is defined , check croppedimage is nil or not

Comment: thaknq for giving replies. but i want to get cropped image from second view to firstview

Comment: in which class above method is written.   firstviewcontroller or secondviewcontroller ??

Comment: - (void)JBCroppableImageView:(JBCroppableImageView *)controller didFinishCroppingImage:(UIImage *)croppedImage{
 } i written this method according to another sample . don't know is it correct or not .any way written this in secondviewController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72223/discussion-between-skt-and-vani-lucky).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save image to user's photo album, you can use UIKit function

```
void UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum ( UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo );
```

read more:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Comment: thanks for giving me reply .but i want to get that cropped image from second view to first view.so i need to save it before i will get into other view .how to save and get that cropped image